# Load and run JS from Ajax response in Iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

How am I able to load and run the ajax response to an iframe, note that the response (see below as an example) I wish to get loaded will run a javascript code.
Please see below my attempt which is failing.

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(responseData,textStatus, xhr)
    {
        var test = document.forms["myform"]["checkbox-email"].value;
        if (test == "on" )
        {                               
            console.log(responseData);
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.open(); 
            iframe.write(responseData);
            iframe.close();

        }

        else
        {
            //.....                         
        }



    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception, error) 
    {
         var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        console.log(msg);

        $('#status').empty();
        $('#status').show();
         $("#status").attr("class", "error");
        $('#status').html("▼ " + msg).addClass('error');                             
        var div = document.getElementById('status');
        div.innerHTML += " ▼";
        div.innerHTML += jqXHR.responseText;                
        //console.log(jqXHR.responseText);

    } 

})
```

**Code Error:**

> Object doesn't support property or method 'write'

**Response to be loaded in an iframe:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 //jQuery.support.cors = true; 
 var attach3 = 'C:\\\\Users\\\\rihanio\\\\Dropbox\\\\Projects\\\\Python_code\\\\work\\\\gateway\\\\%s\\\\%s';
 //var attach3 = 'test'
 function sendEmail(){
   try{
      var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
      var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
      var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0); // value 0 = MailItem

      theMailItem.to = ('PPM.Admin@broadspectrum.com');
      theMailItem.Subject = ('%s');
      theMailItem.Body = ('%s');
      theMailItem.Attachments.Add(attach3);
      theMailItem.display();

      //Show the mail before sending for review purpose
    //You can directly use the theMailItem.send() function
    //if you do not want to show the message.

  }
  catch (err) {
     alert(err.message);
  } 
}

 $(document).ready(function($) {sendEmail(); });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing to the `contentWindow` of the iframe:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(responseData);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Alternatively, you could try setting the `src` property of the iframe using `text/html` mime type:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(responseData);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Also notice that you should insert the iframe somewhere in the DOM (the `document.body` in my example) for this to appear.

Comment: I get the following error for the first example: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference.  as for the second one no errors however the js does not run

Comment: For the first example, could you try adding the iframe to the DOM before writing to the `contentWindow`? I have amended my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You could also try setting the `width` and `height` style properties of the iframe to ensure that it will be visible: `iframe.style="width: 500px;height:500px;";`

Comment: getting somewhere now, i get this error  $(document).ready(function($) {sendEmail(); }); any idea how to get passed it

Comment: Not sure what error you are referring to. What you have shown is some javascript code.

Comment: Yes, I see this, but what is the error you are getting? Any error message?

Comment: '$' is undefined

Comment: okay, that's because you need to specify the full path when including jQuery. Here: `<script src="http://xxxxx/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`. That's also true for the other assets you are including.